# Command Prompt gets open when installing SQL Server using Power Shell

Tags: sql-server, windows, powershell, installation

I am using the following code to setup SQL Server using Power Shell

```
setup.exe /CONFIGURATONFILE=config.ini
```

When i run the above script in power shell it opens the command prompt and runs the setup.
Is there a way in power shell that the command prompt that is being opened (which i can see on the screen) gets opened in the background.

As because of this command prompt opening i get an error "Requires an interactive shell" when i run the power shell script remotely.

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you run Setup.exe with the "Silent" mode (No user-interaction) in addition to the ConfigurationFile? Options are documented here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx for reference.

Try specifying /Q  or /QS

E.g.

```
".\setup.exe /Q /ConfigurationFile=$commandlineparam"
```